# Google Drive Save to Drive Button

Tags: google-drive-api, save, wamp

So I'm learning the Google drive API and learning how to embed a Save to Drive button in a webpage. I have WAMP installed and I'm typing in the address bar the following: localhost/gdrive.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
        <div class="g-savetodrive"
             data-src="http://localhost/test.txt"
             data-filename="test.txt"
             data-sitename="Test document">
        </div>
</html>
```

The gdrive.html should save a file called test.txt to my google drive(test.txt is in the www folder of the WAMP server). However when I sign in and hit the Save button, it doesn't work. It just takes forever(the Google drive loading icon in image below). It doesn't actually save to my Google Drive. This is my first time learning Google Drive's API and is there a reason why this is happening(is it because of localhost.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your client id listed. You'll want to make sure you have the library supplied by Google downloaded. There are 2 main steps.

1. Specify your options, being sure to include YOUR Client ID:

```js
var realtimeOptions = {
  /**
   * Client ID from the console.
   */
  clientId: 'INSERT YOUR CLIENT ID HERE'
  
  /**
   * Add any other options you want.
   */
}
```

2. Initialize the Realtime Loader:

```js
function startRealtime() {
  var realtimeLoader = new rtclient.RealtimeLoader(realtimeOptions);
  realtimeLoader.start();
}
```

Make sure you included the Google libraries necessary:

```html
<!-- Load the Realtime libraries. -->
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>

<!-- Load the utility library. -->
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="realtime-client-utils.js"></script>
```

All the information can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/realtime-quickstart).

Comment: What is the Client ID?

Comment: You have to set up your application in the Google Developers Console. All the info you need is in the link at the end of my original post.